# Python command raise SyntaxError

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install py2deb from pip. I want to make an install for an application, but when I run `pip3 install py2deb`, I get the error message:

```
Error processing line 1 of /home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 173, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 184
      return os.path.basename(__main__.__file__) == f'{name}.py'
                                                               ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running pip 22, python 3.5.2, on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
Please help!

Comment: ``f'{name}.py'`` is an *f-string*, which is only supported since python 3.6 - and you're using python 3.5

Comment: So i need to upgrade python?

Comment: or try to use `python3 -m pip install py2deb`

Comment: Tried that, got the same error. I am upgrading to python 3.10 right now

Comment: As a point of interest, when I run ```sudo apt install python3```, it says it is the latest version. Is this because I am running an old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ok, so I have upgraded to python 3.10 from source code, but it does not seem to have updated pip. Why is that?

Comment: Ok, so I fixed the problem. Instead of running the `pip` of `pip3` commands, I had to run the `pip3.10` command. One alias change later, and everything is back to normal.